# Error when in `shap.prep()` - Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, machine-learning, lightgbm, shap

Following the steps in this [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/06/shap-analysis-in-9-lines/) by Michael Mayer, I'm trying to do a quick SHAP analysis after fitting a LightGBM (multiclass) classifier in R using the sample code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(SHAPforxgboost)
library(lightgbm)

set.seed(111)
x1 <- rnorm(1:2000)
x2 <- rnorm(1:2000)
y <- rnorm(1:2000)

df <- data.frame(x1,x2,y)
df <- 
    df |> 
    mutate(y = abs(y),
                 y = round(y, digits = 0),
                 y = ifelse(y >= 2, 2, y),
                 y = as.character(y)) 


# Define response and features
y <- "y"
x <- c("x1","x2")

# random split
set.seed(83454)
ix <- sample(nrow(df), 0.8 * nrow(df))

dtrain <- lgb.Dataset(data.matrix(df[ix, x]),
                                            label = df[ix, y])
dvalid <- lgb.Dataset(data.matrix(df[-ix, x]),
                                            label = df[-ix, y])

params <- list(
    objective = "multiclass",
    metric = "multi_error",
    learning_rate = 0.05,
    num_leaves = 15,
    num_class = 3
)

fit_lgb <- lgb.train(params,
                     dtrain,
                     nrounds = 89L,
                     valids = list(valid = dvalid),
                     early_stopping_rounds = 20L
)

# SHAP IMPORTANCE
shap <- shap.prep(fit_lgb, X_train = as.matrix(df[,-3]))
```

However, after running `shap.prep(fit_lgb, X_train = as.matrix(df[,-3]))`, I'm receiving the following error: "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"

Any idea what went wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"SHAPforxgboost" does not directly wrap multiclass models, so you would need to prepare the SHAP matrix of the class of interest yourself and then use the general interface of "SHAPforxgboost".

While it also does not provide multi-class SHAP plots, my sister package "shapviz" offers a `which_class` argument to simplify above steps:

```r
library(shapviz)

shap_values <- shapviz(fit_lgb, X_pred = as.matrix(df[,-3]), which_class = 3)

sv_importance(shap_values, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(shap_values, "x1", color_var = "auto")

# Or some single prediction interpretation
sv_waterfall(shap_values, row_id = 1)
```

Beeswarm plot

[image: Beeswarm plot]

Dependence plot

[image: Dependence plot]

Waterfall plot

[image: Waterfall plot]

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation. It works well. Thanks a bunch!